# Help verifying the norm of the resolvent of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, spectral-theory

I'm reading a document where it is said that if
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
then the norm of the resolvent for $z \neq 0$ is given by
$$\|R(z,A)\|= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{1+2|z|^2-\sqrt{1+4|z|^2}}}.$$
I think that if $z\neq 0$ then
$$ R(z,A)=(A-zI)^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}-1/z & -1/z^2\\0 & -1/z \end{pmatrix}$$
and because of that 
$$\|R(z,A)\|=\frac{\sqrt{2|z|^2+1}}{|z|^2}.$$

Am I wrong?.

Answer (score 3):

You have computed the Frobenius norm of the resolvent, whereas the first formula uses the spectral norm of the resolvent.

Comment: Thank you. But, how can I find the spectral norm of the resolvent?.

Comment: I don't know how can I calculate the spectral norm. Can you tell me what I have to do, please?

Comment: The spectral norm of $A$ coincides with the largest spectral value of $A$, i.e., the largest eigenvalue of $A^\top A$.